# requestNewPublishPermissions for facebook android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Currently I check **activeSession.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")** and if it returns false I am requesting for permission

```
private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions";
if(activeSession.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
     postPhotoToFacebook();
} else {
     activeSession.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSION));
}
```

And in Session.Callback, activeSession has permission **"publish_actions"** only if Device have already installed facebook application, But If device have not facebook application and logging through FBDialog, its always returns false to **activeSession.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")**

Comment: which Facebook API you are using..

Comment: I am using latest Facebook SDK.

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  Are you saying that the activeSession only has the permission if the facebook app is installed on the device?  That should be unrelated.  How does this relate to FBDialog?

Comment: when session status is changed, i am requesting for "publish_actions" permission. But still I got "permission error" while i am uploading bitmap using newUploadPhotoRequest(). Its uploaded successfully only if Device have already installed facebook application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Facebook sdk 3.14.x+ thn after april 30th facebook has changed the application testing  and submission process. Posted answer regarding permission related. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23868044/1140237) link

Comment: Now its only working with test users accounts, though App is not in Sandbox mode. How to make my app available for all users?

Comment: to make ur app available for all user .. i mean for live application you need to submit ur app to facebook for review process.and need to follow required steps like submitting ur application(apk or google play url),screenshots where u have used facebook fetures which req permission ,and steps to reach tht screen or functionality so that thy can review ur app.and facebook review team will respond in 7 business days. FYI https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review